# typerror while trying to fetch keys from JS Object

Tags: javascript, firebase

I am trying to fetch data from Firebase Cloud Firestore. When i fetch data from it, it shows it is a object. but i am getting this error.
What i wanted to do it, get Keys list of that object.

This is the code snippet showing problem

```
db.collection('BUSES').get().then(snapshot => {
    // console.log(snapshot.docs)
    snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
        // console.log(doc.data().Stops)
        var a=doc.data().Stops
        console.log(a)
        var b=a.keys()

        console.log(b)
    })
});
```

shows this error.
[image]

this is the original data.
[image]

Comment: Do you want all keys from response ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: yes. it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects don't have a `keys` function by default. You could use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) on it:

```
var b = Object.keys(a);
```

That gets you the keys for all own enumerable properties on the object. that are named with strings (rather than Symbols). There's also [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) which also includes non-enumerable properties (and a couple of others, see [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/)).